# Does this set $S$ contain a nilpotent matrix$?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the set of $3 \times 3$ real matrices $A$ with $A^{T} A = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & 0 \\\
                    0 & 0 & 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 0  
                    \end{pmatrix} $

Then the set $S$ contains a nilpotent matrix.

True/ false $?$

Clearly all the matrices in set $S$ have rank $=1$.
How can I form a nilpotent matrix $A$ such that $A^{T} A$ is

$A^{T} A = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & 0 \\\
                    0 & 0 & 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 0  
                    \end{pmatrix} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Play around with matrices with a single $1$ and other otherwise $0$. You'll find a suitable one pretty quickly.

Comment: Yes ,example - $A =$ an upper triangular matrix with $a_{13} = 1$ and other entries$ = 0$

Comment: @Mathsaddict You can also use $a_{12} = 1$ (that's the concrete one I had in mind, although it makes little difference). But yes, that will do. It is nilpotent, and it is contained in $S$.